# C using case(condition): instead of case value:

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm trying to simplify a long piece of code, and I was wondering if it would be possible to use conditions instead of values for a var after a case statement.

i.e.,

```
switch(var) {
    case(var>1): printf("Var greater than 1");
    case(var<1): printf("Var less than 1");
}
```

Is this possible? If not, any alternatives that have the same general idea?

Comment: you mean like `if(var>1) ... else if (var<1)...`?

Comment: It's *syntactically* valid (and the parentheses aren't necessary). But the expression following `case` has to be a *constant* expression. If `var` were a constant (perhaps a `#define`d macro), then it could compile -- but it would still be clearer to use an `if`/`else`.

Comment: if `var` is unsigned then you can change this to `case 0:`, `case 1:` , and `default:`

Comment: I'm currently using `if` statements. I was just wondering if there was an even more space-saving alternative.

Comment: amongst other problems, there needs to be a 'break;' statement between the cases of a switch() statement.  Otherwise, the execution will run off the end of one case, right into the next case.  There are times when this is desireable.. This code is not one of those times.

Comment: one of the best ways to simplify a long/complex piece of code is to break it onto manageable/self-contained functions.

Answer (score 7):

No. That is not possible. Use `if` and `else if`.

```
if (var > 1) { 
    printf("Var greater than 1");
} else if (var < 1) {
    printf("Var less than 1");
}
```

Comment: And you could add the equivalent of `default`, `} else { /* code here }`.

Answer (score 0):

switch is a conditional statement that is used to match a value in every case. It is not possible what are you looking. You have to do this with If else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since C# 7 the SWITCH statement became a lot more powerfull ; try the following :

```
SWITCH (myVariable){
   CASE var myVal WHEN myVal < 1 :
     ... my code ...
   break;

   CASE var myVal WHEN myVal > 1 :
   ... some other code ...
   break;
}
```

Comment: The question title and tags indicate that it is about C, not C#.

Comment: you're right... do you know how to associate the answer with a C# tag ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't, but it isn't that useful anyway. Except in C#.
The closest thing to that you can do is this:

```
// Program which tells what variable is less than 5
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int a = 5, b = 4, c = 8;
    switch (true)
    {
        case (a < 5):
            cout << "A";
            break;
        case (b < 5):
            cout << "B";
            break;
        /*
        case (c < 5):
            cout << "C";
            break;
        */
        default:
            cout << "None";
            break;
    }
}
```

Since `switch()` compares the value inside of the parenthesis against each of the cases, you can write things such as `switch(5)` or `switch(true)` and then use variables or condition expressions in each of the cases.
But even doing so, there are two other problems: **1.-** all variables implied in such cases must be constant or it won't compile, (see the code) and **2.-** Switch statements don't allow repeating any case, as you can see, I comented out the last case since there were already one false condition so it would've not compiled.

Comment: This is not possible in C.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but with a simple trick:

```
var myVal = 'something' ;

if (myVal < 1) {
    myVal = 0;
}

if (myVal >= 1){
    myVal = 1;
}

switch (myVariable) {
    case 0:  
      ... my code ...;
      break;

    case 1:      
      ... some other code ...;
      break;
```